# Как в родительской категории получить товары из дочерних категорий?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Битый час не могу справиться с задачей)
Пишу на Laravel, использую связь eloquent.
Мне нужно отобразить на странице категории, в которых есть товары. Нет товаров - категорию не отображать. По идее должно быть все просто, но видимо не для меня))

Пример:

```
Одежда
   Футболки и поло
      Футболки
      Поло
      Лонгсливы
```

По факту, товары лежат в конечной категории (Например футболки), но в таком случае категория "Одежда" не должна быть пустой.
Для того, чтобы выводить категории с продуктами использую такие связи в модели Category:

```
public function childrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function allChildrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->childrenCategories()->with(['allChildrenCategories', 'products']);
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'category_title','title')->where('stock', 'in-stock');
    }
```

В контроллере CategoryController:

```
$allChildCategories = Category::where('name', $categoryName->name)->with('allChildrenCategories')->get()->toArray();
```

Ну и пробу вывести это:

```
dump($allChildCategories);
```

Получаю почти то, что нужно. Но, естественно, при таком раскладе "products" содержит только конечная категория. А мне нужно, чтобы родительская категория в таком случае тоже содержала продукты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть идеи, как такое можно реализовать?

P.S. Возможно мой подход в корне не верен, поэтому строго не судите, я только начинаю разбираться))

Comment: Штатными средствами вы будете долго копаться, посмотрите в Google по запросам "Laravel tree", что в итоге выдаст вам что-то вроде [NestedSet](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset), или ответы с [англоязычного SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748528/laravel-display-all-parent-categories-as-tree-for-a-specific-sub-category)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov не подскажешь, как получить не все данные о товаре, а лишь узнать их количество? А лучше даже не количество, а просто есть они или нет. Пробую так, но все ломается:
`public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_title', 'title')->where('stock', 'in-stock')->count();
    }` Мне же фактически не нужны все данные о товарах, а надо лишь узнать, есть они или нет. Я зря нагружаю базу.

Comment: Можно составить базовый запрос к БД как указано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries) без использования Eloquent.